# Where can I change the default value for vertex color attribute?

Tags: vertices, color, vertex-colors, vertex-paint, source-code

I am currently trying to see if I can make a change to the blender code to allow me to have a default value of the vertex color attribute to (0,0,0,0) instead of (1,1,1,1) when I create a primitive object but I am currently struggling to find where this variable is set within the blender files

Comment: Default value of what property? I assume you know how to recompile Blender? https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender. The code is here https://github.com/blender/blender

Comment: What do you mean by "vertex color"  in the title of your question? - You can change the colour of almost anything via Edit > Properties > Themes > 3D Viewport in Blender, But I suspect that you're not asking about that?